# Check port function

Tags: java, ip, port

How can I check that which port for which function in java ?
Example:

Port xx is for webserver

Port xx is for fpt server

port xx is for mail server.
...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're opening connections to the ports and trying every possible server protocol, you won't be able to check which service is accessible through a given port.

An example: Port 80 ist HTTPd, but the server admin could map port 80 to smtpd, so you have to connect to the port and try http, smtp, ssh, ....

**Edit**

I would say it's only feasible for some protocols like HTTP and SMTP. If the server side is encrypted, you can't tell which service is answering. There are lots of possible services (check the first comment's link), encrypted services, and other problems awaiting you :)

Comment: But if you only want the standard port numbers, you can parse this file for example: http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers

Comment: @Matten: Thanks for help. Could you explain more detail your answer. I don't want to use standard port numbers. I want to open connection to the ports and "try every possible server protocol". How can I try it?

Comment: In germany, doing things like this is not allowed and I would get arrested if someone gets it :) If you REALLY want to do something like this, which is very advanced network programming, you should check the code of tools like Nmap (http://nmap.org/) or Jmap (http://tomsalmon.eu/jmap-java-port-scanner/)

Comment: One step back, checking out jmap reveals that they are doing like biziclop said, only mapping open ports to the appropriate protocols.